# How to remove the title background from a transparent ActionBar?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionmode

I'm using a transparent ActionBar with a white title. Unfortunately the title has its own background.
[image]

This is my styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/app_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#ff077fb1</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/app_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff077fb1</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/app_color</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Here is the toolbar used:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
sothree:theme="@style/MyActionBar">
```

How can I get rid of that blue title background?

Comment: Why actionbar style parent is Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar?

Comment: It's not an issue @Harry he uses a toolbar

Comment: I changed to Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar but that blue background remains.

Comment: What if you dont use style and apply background in toolbar itself? and also try using other than NoActionBar

Comment: Like I said @Harry NoActionbar is not an issue coz he's defining a toolbar im using the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by removing

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
<item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
```

from styles.xml and adding the background color programatically to the toolbar using

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this when defining textAppearance in toolbar

```
sothree:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbar.TextAppearance"
```

**style**

```
    <style name="MyToolbar.TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/toolbar_title_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/mytransparentcolor</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work but I found a way and posted the answer here. Anyway, thanks for your advice